# Regex to find multiple matches within a String which starts and ends with specific character

Tags: java, regex

Need to find the matches of a string using regex that starts with "Contains" and ends with "."

`String statement="SOME TEXT Contains one, ones and onness. SOME TEXT Contains two. Contains three";`

Expected matches : 1) `Contains one ones and onness.`   2) `Contains two.`

Should not match : `Contains three` as it does not ends with "."

Currently I am using the following regex in my java code and ending up getting the above mentioned should not match criteria also.

`Contains[^\.]*` -- //Regex which says anything that starts with "Contains" followed by anything except "."

Any idea on what regex would fit my requirement?

Comment: StringNAME.split("SOME  TEXT"); will returen an array of Strings

Comment: "^Contains*\.$"
Starts with contains, than an optional amount of other input, then ends with .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
"Contains[^.]+\\."
```

The second dot was escaped to match `.` literally.

Comment: Contains may not the start of the line and "." need not be the end of the line. this does not work for me.

Comment: @LGAP, I updated the answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` cannot be eager.

`"Contains.*?\\."`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
public static void main(String... strings) {
    String statement="SOME TEXT Contains one, ones and onness. SOME TEXT Contains two. Contains three";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Contains.*?\\.)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(statement);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
Contains one, ones and onness.
Contains two.
```